# D3: transitions not working when calling zoom function

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have created a setup with D3 in react, where I e.g. can call a function `yTranslate` to make a vertical translation - it works as it is, but if I try to add a transition no translation is made. I am not really sure whether I am maybe adding the transition at the wrong place?

```
yTranslation = (trans_y) => {
  if (this.svgRef.current) {
    d3
      .select(this.svgRef.current)
      .transition().duration(500) //not working
      .call(
        this.getZoomBehaviour(this.onZoom).transform,
        d3.zoomIdentity
          .scale(this.state.zoom_transform.k)
          .translate(this.state.zoom_transform.x / this.state.zoom_transform.k,
          trans_y / this.state.zoom_transform.k)
      );
  }
}

getZoomBehaviour = (onzoom) => {

  ...

  return d3
    .zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 40])
    .translateExtent(trans_extent)
    .extent(extent)
    .on('zoom', onzoom);
}

onZoom = (e) => {  
  if (!isNaN(e.transform.x) && !isNaN(e.transform.y) && !isNaN(e.transform.k)) {
    this.setState({ zoom_transform: e.transform });
  }
}
```

If I for example call the function `yTranslate` with -103 without having the transition included I can by console.logging in the `onZoom` function see that it only is called once and that `e.transform.y` now is -103 - but if I call the function with the transitions included, I can see that `onZoom` is called multiple times and `e.transform.y` stays as it was before calling the function.

**Edit:** It might somehow be related to how I define the translation - it works when transitions aren't included, but with transitions included I am also able to make a horizontal translation or zoom, it only seems to be vertical translation that doesn't work...

**Solution:** The issue seems to lie in my `onZoom` function in something that I hadn't included:

```
onZoom = (e) => {
  const new_transform = e.transform;
  if (new_transform.k !== this.state.zoom_transform.k) {
    new_transform.y = this.state.zoom_transform.y;
  }

  if (!isNaN(new_transform.x) && !isNaN(new_transform.y) && 
      !isNaN(new_transform.k)) {
    this.setState({ zoom_transform: new_transform });
  }
}
```

The whole idea here is that I only want to be able to zoom in the x-direction, but when making transitions it seems that the zoom level also changes - I guess my solution will be to give the onZoom function a variable telling it that it shouldn't change the y variable :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const x = this.state.zoom_transform.x / this.state.zoom_transform.k;
const y = trans_y / this.state.zoom_transform.k;
d3.select(this.svgRef.current)
  .transition().duration(500)
  .attr('transform', `translate(${x},${y})`);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - however I do not think that this works for my case, as I don't as such translate the svg. My setup is more built up around using the zoom_transform - I use it for rescaling the xScale, and for the vertical translation i use zoom_transform.y to transform a g element :)

Comment: Did you try it? Do you see an error in the console?

Comment: I did try it, yes - there was no error, and it did in fact transform the svg however this is not what I want - I am working on a viz that is a bar graph that is split into multiple components, so transforming the svg just transforms the bars - I need the zoom_transform so that I can rescale the xScale which will then affect the bars and the axis, and then I use zoom_transform.y for the vertical translation (I have zoom/panning in the x-direction and only panning in the y-direction which is an ordinal scale), which is used for transforming g elements :)

Comment: Try to apply transform on your <g> element instead of whole <svg>

Comment: The issue is that I would have to transform multiple g elements, and I would in some other way then need to keep track of it, because I also use zoom_transform.y in other functions when e.g. making a horizontal translation, but I actually just discovered the bug - I will update the card accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: The issue seems to lie in my onZoom function in something that I hadn't included:

```
onZoom = (e) => {
  const new_transform = e.transform;
  if (new_transform.k !== this.state.zoom_transform.k) {
    new_transform.y = this.state.zoom_transform.y;
  }

  if (!isNaN(new_transform.x) && !isNaN(new_transform.y) && 
      !isNaN(new_transform.k)) {
    this.setState({ zoom_transform: new_transform });
  }
}
```

The whole idea here is that I only want to be able to zoom in the x-direction, but when making transitions it seems that the zoom level also changes - I guess my solution will be to give the onZoom function a variable telling it that it shouldn't change the y variable :)